# How can I get the last post while on the first post for pagination? As if it were infinite

Tags: posts, loop, pagination

The title might be a little bit confusing. So I'm trying to do the pagination for my posts and it's working fine, but I'd like to have it so that while I'm on the first post I can see the last post in the pagination for `get_previous_post` and vice versa, so if I'm on the last post I see the first for `get_next_post`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="post-pagination">
    <!-- Previous Post -->
    <?php
        $prevPost = get_previous_post();
        $prevThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($prevPost->ID);
    ?>
    <?php if( $prevPost ) : ?>
    <div class="prev-post" style="background: url('<?php echo $prevThumb; ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="post-pagination-title">
            <?php previous_post_link( '%link', __( '<div class="sub-title">Previous</div> <h2>%title</h2>', 'text-domain' ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Next Post -->
    <?php
        $nextPost = get_next_post();
        $nextThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($nextPost->ID);
    ?>
    <?php if( $nextPost ) : ?>
    <div class="next-post" style="background: url('<?php echo $nextThumb; ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="post-pagination-title">
            <?php next_post_link( '%link',__( '<div class="sub-title">Next</div> <h2>%title</h2>', 'text-domain' ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm afraid it can be very confusing for users...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to implement, can you describe it from a user facing non-technical visual browser perspective? Rather than a developer/code post oriented perspective?

Comment: The only way I think i can further explain this is like infinite pagination.